# How can I see all the text accumulated in JsonWriter during a JsonConverter class debugging?

Tags: c#, json.net

How can I see all the **text** accumulated in `JsonWriter` during a `JsonConverter` class debugging ?

```
class LookupConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var lu = value as Lookup<string, MyClass>;
        foreach (var i in lu.SelectMany(nodes => nodes))
        {
            // I want to setup a breakpoint here and examine the 
            // "text" accumulated in `writer`...
        }
    }
    /*
    ...
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it:

```
((Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter)(writer))._writer.ToString()
```